# Laptop HDD runs very hot (even in idle state)

Tags: release-freya, system, hardware, disk-management, temperature

I wanted to ask about this because it didn't happened to me before with other linux distributions (i.e Fedora or Mint)

For whatever reason the HDD in the laptop runs very hot, so hot that is really uncomfortable to write with my hand touching the laptop.

I've tried several software pieces to check what may be happening and I detected a high I/O from gala.

- Why does "gala" have an I/O percentage so high?
- Is this normal even in idle state?

iotop

```
max@linux-max:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +44.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +50.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +27.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:       +127.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +49.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +50.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

top

```
max@linux-max:~$ top
top - 11:27:24 up  1:01,  6 users,  load average: 0.26, 0.30, 0.33
Tasks: 226 total,   1 running, 225 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.8 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.9 id,  2.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  16309500 total,  3468488 used, 12841012 free,   446700 buffers
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,        0 used,  2097148 free.  1350980 cached Mem
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7714 root      20   0   80308  15736   7348 S   4.6  0.1   0:23.06 iotop
 1350 root      20   0  340740  73144  56096 S   3.7  0.4   1:24.67 Xorg
 2414 max       20   0  613640  36952  26424 S   3.3  0.2   0:21.44 pantheon-termin
 2550 max       20   0 1905892 869704  98484 S   3.0  5.3   8:30.09 firefox
 2005 max       20   0 1035020 123108  37832 S   2.7  0.8   0:39.35 gala
```

iotop

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
 2005 be/4 max         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 11.34 % gala
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]
 2054 be/4 max         0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % indicator-messages-service
    7 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
```

smartctl

```
max@linux-max:~$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep Temperature_Cel
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   056   045    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 20/36)
```

Any suggestions on what else to check or what can I do to lower the temperature for the HDD would be greatly appreciated.

Max

Comment: You might do a smart test on your hdd. It might be a faulty drive.